# JS error when creating Youtube background

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to create a youtube video background with the help of Jquery. I referred to https://github.com/rochestb/jQuery.YoutubeBackground and create a page for the same. I was able to successfully play the video in the background but when the page loads I get a JS error
**"JavaScript exception: Error calling selector function:TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined**"

Below is the link for my page.
http://creativated.com/thetest/index.html

Please help me find the rootcause.

Regards
Creativated Dev

Answer (score 1):

Your museutils.js script uses deprecated method [.browser()](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

You still can add it as plugin [jQuery browser plugin](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin)

Comment: Just tried that and getting a new error.exception: Error calling selector function:TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined"

Comment: I think you need to look where is fired, probably another old library